# Prevent full screen applications from minimizing when they lose focus?

Tags: windows-7

I'm playing some Steam games on fullscreen, but they only use one monitor. If I try to use my browser on my second monitor, the game minimizes.

Is it possible to prevent a full=screen application from minimizing when it loses focus?

I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no.

Games in particular rely on a [hardware overlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_overlay) to do their drawing when in fullscreen mode. This method has a speed advantage because the game can bypass Windows completely and write frames directly to the graphics output buffer.

When a game is in windowed mode, the operating system has control of the output buffer, so the game must render frames by going through the operating system's window manager.  This process is slower because the output buffer must be shared with all the other windows on the screen.

Only one output buffer can be visible on the screen at a time, so if your game has control of it, it must be minimized in order to switch back to Windows' output buffer.

The only solution would be to run your game in windowed mode (if that's an option) and have it maximized on one screen.  But depending on the game, that'll cost you a few FPS.

Answer (score 0):

don't listen to ppl saying that it can't be done with exclusive fullscreen. the real issue is that when you alt-tab it continues to place the mouse positioning on your primary monitor, which now is going to be below the fullscreen application, bringing your desktop to the front layer of windows.

if you change your primary monitor to the non-game monitor while playing, you should be able to alt-tab without the game minimizing, and you'll clearly be able to see where it repositions your mouse and by doing so explain what was causing it to minimize before.......

i have an autohotkey script i use to swap primary display and also launch my game(s) and another event trigger in the autohotkey script to swap primary display back when it sees the game executable terminate.

there's also a feature in Steam's "Big Picture" mode that allows you to specify which monitor you want to be your primary while gaming.  It's designed to switch your primary to a different monitor for gaming then restore it when complete. But you can use it for the opposite also by specifying the non-game monitor as the one you're going to game on and simply moving the full screen game back to the other monitor with alt-enter then win-shift-left/right then another alt-enter..

then when you're done with the game, steam will automatically swap your primary monitor back to where it was.

hope this helps.

btw.. sayeed wasn't wrong about exclusive fullscreen writing directly to the output buffer, but windows can still manage that stream and control the layer at which it is streaming so that it properly nests between windows.

otherwise the method i just suggested wouldn't work.. and it does. i alt-tabbed out of an unreal engine exclusive fullscreen game to type this and i'm staring right at the game right now... not minimized.

i know this is necroposting, and likely wasn't a valid solution at the time.. but people searching for an answer today will find it and be completely mislead unless an updated answer is provided to fit the times.